# In Julia, insert commas into integers for printing like Python 3.6+

Tags: python, julia

I want to insert commas into large integers for printing.

```
julia> println(123456789)  # Some kind of flag/feature inserts commas.
"123,456,789"
```

In Python 3.6+ this is easy to do:

```
>>> print(f"{123456789:,d}")
123,456,789
```

However, it does not appear that the standard Julia print/println functions have this feature at the present time.  What can I do using just the print/println functions?

Comment: How about the [Formatting.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/Formatting.jl) package?

Comment: Yes, that works, but I wanted to see what could be done without using a package.  I have tried the Formatting package, but I wish for something as straight forward as Python 3.6+ string interpolation.  My "answer" is not as straight forward as Python's, but it does work in Julia without using a package.

Comment: Well, at least with a package there's some vetting and the possibility of submitting issues, etc. It may be fun, and possibly instructive, to do cross-translation between languages, but ultimately the tools were intended for other purposes.

Comment: I agree that different tools can have different purposes, but it seems to me *as a newbie to Julia* that the string interpolation of numbers Julia story can be improved.  As a numerical computing language it seems like the easy formatting of large numbers should be builtin to Julia's string interpolation.  Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: I think the Julia developers are trying to keep the base Julia lean and performant while also encouraging package development. If you think base Julia should have enhanced features, perhaps [submitting an issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues) would be a positive step. There, the developers and concerned users can discuss options, design philosophy, etc., better than can be done at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion and helpful link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the most straightforward way in some languages would be to use the `'` format modifier in `printf`. I Julia this WOULD look like so:

```
using Printf # a stdlib that ships with julia which defines @printf
@printf "%'d" 12345678
```

However, unfortunately, this flag is not yet supported as you can see from the error you'll get:

```
julia> @printf "%'d" 12345678
ERROR: LoadError: printf format flag ' not yet supported
```

If you like this feature, maybe you should think about adding it to the [Printf](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/Printf/#Printf-1) stdlib so that everyone would benefit from it. I don't know how difficult this would be though.

UPDATE: Note that although the macro is defined in stdlib Printf, the error above is explicitly thrown in `Base/printf.jl:48`. I also filed an issue [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/29077)

Comment: Thanks for useful explanation and suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function based on a Regex from "Regular Expressions Cookbook," by Goyvaerts and Levithan, O'Reilly, 2nd Ed, p. 402, that inserts commas into integers returning a string.

```
function commas(num::Integer)
    str = string(num)
    return replace(str, r"(?<=[0-9])(?=(?:[0-9]{3})+(?![0-9]))" => ",")
end

println(commas(123456789))
println(commas(123))
println(commas(123456789123456789123456789123456789))

""" Output
123,456,789
123
123,456,789,123,456,789,123,456,789,123,456,789
"""
```