# Commas in Julia 1.0 Numbers of Any Kind

Tags: julia

I would like a function in Julia code, `num2str`, that would add commas or a specified delimiter, in the appropriate places on the left side of the decimal point for any kind of valid Julia number, including BigInt and BigFloat.  It would return a string for printing.

For example:

```
flt1 = 122234.141567
println("flt1 num2str($flt1) = ", num2str(flt1))
# Expected output is:
flt1 num2str(122234.141567) = 122,234.141567
```

I want to use this function with the `print` and `println` built-in functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was partially answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52213829/in-julia-insert-commas-into-integers-for-printing-like-python-3-6/52216395#52216395), i.e, for integers.  The following function should answer the need for floats and "big" numbers.

```
"""
 For any valid number, add appropriate delimiters.
 See "Regular Expressions Cookbook," by Goyvaerts and Levithan, O'Reilly, 2nd Ed, 
 p. 402, for Regex that inserts commas into integers returning a string.
"""
function num2str(num::Number; delim=",")
   decimal_point = "."
   str = string(num)
   strs = split(str, decimal_point)
   left_str = strs[1]
   right_str = length(strs) > 1 ? strs[2] : ""
   left_str = replace(left_str, r"(?<=[0-9])(?=(?:[0-9]{3})+(?![0-9]))" => delim)
   decimal_point = occursin(decimal_point, str) ? decimal_point : ""
   return left_str * decimal_point * right_str
end

# Test integers, BigInts, floats, and BigFloats:
int0 = 0
int1 = 123
int2 = 123456789
big1 = big"123"
big2 = big"123456789123456789"
flt1 = 122234.141567
flt2 = 7.12345e9
big3 = big"260123.0"
big4 = big"7.12345e9"

setprecision(20)
println("int0 num2str($int0) \t\t\t\t = ", num2str(int0))
println("int1 num2str($int1) \t\t\t\t = ", num2str(int1))
println("int2 num2str($int2) \t\t\t = ", num2str(int2))
println("big1 num2str($big1) \t\t\t\t = ", num2str(big1))
println("big2 num2str($big2) \t\t = ", num2str(big2))
println("big2 num2str($big2) delim is _ \t = ", num2str(big2, delim="_"))
println("flt1 num2str($flt1) \t\t\t = ", num2str(flt1))
println("flt1 num2str($flt1) delim is _ \t\t = ", num2str(flt1, delim="_"))
println("flt2 num2str($flt2) \t\t\t = ", num2str(flt2))
println("big3 num2str($big3) \t\t\t = ", num2str(big3))
println("big4 num2str($big4) \t\t\t = ", num2str(big4))
println("big4 num2str($big4) delim is _ \t\t = ", num2str(big4, delim="_"))

## ============================== Output ===================================
int0 num2str(0)                                  = 0
int1 num2str(123)                                = 123
int2 num2str(123456789)                          = 123,456,789
big1 num2str(123)                                = 123
big2 num2str(123456789123456789)                 = 123,456,789,123,456,789
big2 num2str(123456789123456789) delim is _      = 123_456_789_123_456_789
flt1 num2str(122234.141567)                      = 122,234.141567
flt1 num2str(122234.141567) delim is _           = 122_234.141567
flt2 num2str(7.12345e9)                          = 7.12345e9
big3 num2str(2.60123e+05)                        = 2.60123e+05
big4 num2str(7.12345e+09)                        = 7.12345e+09
big4 num2str(7.12345e+09) delim is _             = 7.12345e+09
```

I expect the ability to add comma delimiters will eventually be added to either `print/println` and/or `@printf`.  Until then, this seems to work.

Comment: I suspect it won't be added to `print` variants. There is a deliberate focus in Julia on keeping `Base` as trim as possible, which means a lot of functionality like this is in packages (many of which are written by core developers). In this case, I'm fairly sure the functionality you are after is provided in [Formatting.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/Formatting.jl) which offers both C and Python style numeric formatting. Cheers.

Comment: I would not be surprised if you are right.  However, one of the things I really liked about Python 3.6+ is that all this format stuff is in the core print function using string interpolation with f-strings.  I wish that was in base Julia, but I really like Julia anyway.

Comment: I'm neutral on this issue :-)  However, I do recall there was quite a bit of discussion around exactly this topic in the community, but overall the most weight, especially among the core devs, was in favour of keeping `Base` as slim as possible. There are definitely arguments going both ways though.